# hibernate : use of query.uniquevalue()

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

If there is only one record matching the query ,then `query.list()` will only return one record.Then what is the use of `query.uniqueResult()`? because in case there are more than one record matching the query it would throw `NonUniqueResultException`.What is use of this method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `query.uniqueResult()` if you are sure you get only one record. For instance when you search for a unique identifier.

If you do something like

```
select * from person where id =1
```

you can use `query.uniqueResult()` because you get only one or zero records.

If you do somethink like

```
select * from person where name  = 'Jens'
```

you  have to use  `query.list()` because you can get more than one record.

Comment: can somebody give me a clear view of the scenarios it is really useful

Answer (score 0):

As [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#uniqueResult%28%29) states:

> Convenience method to return a single instance that matches the query, or null if the query returns no results.
>
> Returns:
>      the single result or null
>   Throws:
>      NonUniqueResultException - if there is more than one matching result

So if you are sure that only one result is going to be returned, then you can use this convenience method to obtain directly the result instead of a list (and so avoiding the verbose use of `result.get(0)`). If you failed in your suposition of uniqueness then the exception is thrown.

Comment: I believe for using this i need to have a look at the database first ...;)